# Why can't I target this link with a class

Tags: html, css

unlink the similar question

[Why can't I target the links in this class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705140/why-cant-i-target-the-links-in-this-class)

I cannot seem to target a link with a class next to another link with a class.

The html.

```
<div class="tribe-events-cal-links">

<a class="tribe-events-gcal tribe-events-button" href="#" title="Add to Google Calendar">+ Google Calendar</a>

<a class="tribe-events-ical tribe-events-button" href="http://localhost/bcu/event/test/?ical=1&amp;tribe_display=">+ iCal Import</a>

</div>
```

I would like to be able to `display: none;` but I cannot seem to target that specific link.

I have tried.

```
tribe-events-ical >a {
    display: none;
}
```

and all the varients but I believe I am doing it wrong and i cannot seem to find a example oh how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: why not just `.tribe-events-ical` or `a.tribe-events-ical`

Comment: I've tried using just that class although it would not work.

Comment: then you should use developer tools or firebug to inspect the element. chances are you are having some other styles taking higher priority. for example, a.tribal-events-ical will supersede .tribal-events-ical because it is more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to review your CSS selectors. A class is defined with a leading `.` and the element should precede it.

So your CSS should be:

```
a.tribe-events-ical {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, I'm sure this is correct but i'm having trouble with it still, I'm really sorry but could you please have a look at this picture as it's hard to show the code as it is php generated, http://i.imgur.com/96dT6L6.png (It is still not working with this setup)

Comment: Not quite sure what that picture is supposed to show? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Ah sorry for not making my point clear, The css shown as taken from your advice is not working on the html. The top picture shows the element i would like hidden and the css is what I am trying to use to hide it although it is not hidden.

Comment: Ah bingo! It was being overridden i had to add a !important! thank you for your advice!